# Printing j in external loop when no print(j) specified - why?

Tags: python

(Newbie question, please bear with me...)

For the following code:

```
x = 4 
for j in range(x):     
    for i in range(x):         
        print(i)         
        x = 2
```

Python prints the following:

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
0
1
0
1
```

... and I do not understand why it prints the first iteration of 0 1 2 3 when there is no print(j) command, only print(i). What purpose at all do the line "for j in range(x):" and j specifically serve?

This is an example from the book "Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python" by John Guttag (used in the MIT courses).

Comment: python generated the i loop with range(4) for the first time. so it prints i from 0 to 3. Afterwords, it generates the next loop with range(2) so it prints 0 to 1, three more times.

Comment: Jep the range() functions just generates a list once. The list generate by range() wil not change until the loop is finished and the loop is again initialized.

Comment: @EranMoshe Ok, but it only asks to print(i) for x = 2, never asks to iterate or print(j) and in the output it has printed for j in range(x) [when x = 4] in addition to i.

Comment: it doesn't `print(j)`. It only prints `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop `for j in range(x):` is evaluated one time with `x=4`, it means that the inner loop will be evaluated 4 times with j=0,1,2,3.

You have then to ask yourself what is the value of `x` when the expression `for i in range(x):` is evaluated.

At the first evaluation `x` is 4, the inner loop is executed with 0,1,2,3 for `i`.

At the second evaluation `x` is 2, the inner loop is executed with 0,1 for `i`

For the third and fourth evaluation `x` is also `2`, and the inner loop is executed with 0,1 for `i`.

Comment: thank you, I understand this theoretically, but then what is the role of j? Why do we even need j in this example, couldn´t we simply use i everywhere and the output would be the same?

Comment: j is the counter for the outer loop. It's not used explicitly inside any loop but it's necessary to count the number of execution of the outer loop.

Comment: I just replaced j with i to see what would happen and it prints exactly the same output as when using j. So I still don´t fully understand why we need to use a different variable than i in the outer loop...

Comment: In this case, it's not necessary. `i` is implicitly assigned at the being of each for loop. But it much more clear if you use two distinct variables.